# Selenium's remote web driver for firefox cannot connect - FF 26 and Selenium Server 2.39

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

FireFox web driver in selenium is unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

I only get this after remote driver is running for a while.

I am using the latest versions of FF and Selenium server. Does anybody know if it is the selenium and FireFox issue and knows the latest stable match?

or maybe I am missing something here?

I am using C# library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue here.

C# on Windows:

```
Selenium v2.39 - and Firefox v25 -> Works for me
Selenium v2.39 - and Firefox v26 -> Timeout after 45 seconds
```

However - Python on Ubuntu:

```
Selenium v2.39 and Firefox v26 -> Works for me
```